# Rails find method didn't use my foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have the following two Models:

```
class TopicContent < ActiveRecord::Base
 unloadable
 belongs_to :topic 
end
```

and

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
 unloadable
 has_one :topic_content
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic_content
end
```

And the following show action, which get the :id from the selected topic:

```
def show
 @text = TopicContent.find(params[:id])
end
```

The problem is, that the **find** method always take the **primary-key(id)** instead of **foreign-key (topic_id)**  from the TopicContent table.

Is there something wrong with my defined associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find(primary_key)` always retrieves the records from database based on `primary key`.

Use `.find_by(conditions)` instead as it finds the first record matching conditions passed to it.

For eg:

```
@text = TopicContent.find_by(topic_id: params[:id])
```

Comment: **Thx** i use the dynamic way, which also work:

@text = TopicContent.find_by_topic_id(params[:id])

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the TopicContent via the Topic.

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(:topic_id)
  @text = @topic.topic_content
end
```

This is assuming you have your routes set up as well.